# oracle function wrong type argument from .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

this is my code (i tried to change the name for security reason)

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["D"]))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("D", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("D", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["D"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("E", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("E", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["F"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["F"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["G"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("G", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("G", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["G"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["H"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("H", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("H", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["H"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("I", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("I", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["J"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("J", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("J", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["J"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("K", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("K", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["L"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("L", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("L", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["L"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["M"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("M", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("M", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["M"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["N"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("N", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("N", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["N"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("O", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("O", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["P"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["P"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Q"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Q"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("R", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("R", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["R"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("S", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("S", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["S"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["T"]))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("T", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("T", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["T"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["U"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("U", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("U", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["U"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["V"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("V", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("V", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["V"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["W"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("W", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Double;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("W", double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["W"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Double;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["X"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("X", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("X", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["X"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Y"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Y", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Y", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Y"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Z"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Z", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Z", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Z"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("A1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("B1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("C1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["C1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("E1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("E1", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["E1"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["F1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("F1", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["F1"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["G1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("G1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("G1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["G1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["H1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("H1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("H1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["H1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("I1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("I1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["I1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["J1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("J1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("J1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["J1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("K1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("K1", int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["K1"].ToString())).OracleType = OracleType.Number;

    }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["L1"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("L1", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("L1", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["L1"].ToString()).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

    }
```

and also these

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("M1", "24234234234").OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("N1", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")).OracleType = OracleType.DateTime;//'18/MAY/2015'
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("O1", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")).OracleType = OracleType.DateTime;
```

the actual types for these parameter is:

```
A Numeric(2)
B Varchar(8)
C Varchar(40)
D Numeric(4)
E Numeric(4)
F Numeric(4)
G Numeric(6)
H Numeric(3)
I Numeric(1)
J Varchar(1)
K Varchar(35)
L Numeric(4)
M Numeric(3)
N Numeric(6)
O Numeric(8)
P Numeric(3)
Q Numeric(4)
R Numeric(3)
S Numeric(6)
T Numeric(8)
U Numeric(3)
V Varchar(35)
W Numeric(20,6)
X Varchar(3)
Y Varchar(255)
Z Numeric(1)
A1 Varchar(80)
B1 Varchar(80)
C1 Varchar(5)
D1 Varchar(50)
E1 Numeric(4)
F1 Numeric(4)
G1 Varchar(40)
H1 Varchar(40)
I1 Varchar(40)
J1 Varchar(40)
K1 Numeric(4)
L1 Varchar(1)
M1 Varchar(35)
N1 Datetime
O1 Date
```

i am getting error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'my function name'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

i print the number of parameter in the run time and it is 41 (correct), so the wrong is one of these types. help please i have been trying two days to sovle it and not success yet.

Comment: @Asad sorry the code has already been in the client, i am just doing some *inhancement* to the real function. it is not me who wrote it

Comment: A function that accepts 41 parameters seems like a rather poor design to begin with.  You'd need to post the signature of your function for us to be able to guess which parameter is incorrect.  I assume that you've done this at some point in the past two days.  Assuming it isn't blindingly obvious, and assuming that you can't fix the function signature, I'd strongly suggest building a simple case and iterating up.  Can you create a function that does nothing, accepts 1 parameter, and call that?  If you can, then you can slowly add parameters until you identify your problem.

Comment: @JustinCave sorry i can't do that, this function has already been in the customer (client), and i have improved the internal functionality for the function, i don't even have access to oracle server, just oracle client, i know it is bad design, but this is business, as you know, clients can be sometimes old fasion and we have to deal with that

Comment: i mean now i don't have access, and i can't order a new access (this client is strict )

Comment: No idea what you're trying to say here.  You say you "improved the internal functionality for the function".  Was the code that called the function working before?  If so, you must have changed the signature of the function and not changed the signature of the caller.  You say that you don't have access to the server but you do have access to the "oracle client".  That doesn't make sense.  If you have access to the Oracle client, you should be able to connect to the database to gather the information you need.

Comment: @JustinCave it is long story here, please just if you can help in this function noting that i can't change anything. if you can't it is okay

Comment: Without seeing the signature of the function there's not really much anyone can do to help.

Comment: @BobJarvis i did show u the variable types and the error, please why is this not possible?

Comment: @BobJarvis i might have figured the problem, the function takes in and out parameters, and now the code just has the in parameters, should i add the out parameters as well?

Comment: @JustinCave do i need to identify the output parameters as well?

Comment: Yes (obviously).  If there are `out` parameters, you'd need to provide those as well in your call.  As it sits, though, it's impossible to help you because we have no idea what your function's actual signature is.

Comment: ok, take a step back and what has changed? If you are using git take a look at the diff, or the blame and see what is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you are missing one parameted as well as wrong type on one of them.

"D1" is the missing part and "P" is incorrect type (based on your list of parameters) so it should be changed from this:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["P"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;
    }
```

to this:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["P"].ToString()))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P", DBNull.Value).OracleType = OracleType.Number;
    }
```

Comment: i already found the `P` error and it still gives me the same error (after the correction), but i found that the code just provides the in parameters, should i specify the out paramter as well?

Comment: for the D1, it was just a type when trying to hide the actual names,

Comment: If you have no other overload for the method, then yes. You should also specify the out parameters.